# Defer target until variable set

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project where you can build for multiple platforms, architectures, etc. I need to be able to set various variables based on the target before compiling any source files. But what's happening is the non-platform specific files are getting compiled immediately and then the platform specific ones didn't get compiled at all.

Below calling "make foobar_mac", foo.o gets created but bar.mac.o does not and therefore during the final link bar.mac.o is missing.

```
OBJS = foo.c bar.$(PLATFORM).c

%.o : %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

foobar_mac: PLATFORM := mac
foobar_mac: $(OBJS)

foobar_win: PLATFORM := win
foobar_win: $(OBJS)
```

Comment: The prerequisites of a target (`foobar_mac : $(OBJS)`) are expanded as the makefile is parsed.  Target-specific variables are not set until later when make tries to run the recipe: they only have effect within the recipe and can't be used to modify the prerequisites of a targets.  When make expands `foobar_mac : $(OBJS)` the variable `PLATFORM` is set to the empty string, so you get a prerequisite of `bar..c`.

Comment: You could go all the way and write a fully dynamic makefile instead of mixing static and dynamic portions like with the current attempt. You sacrifice simplicity anyways, so this wouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to get what you want.  One way is to use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) to delay the expansion until after the target-specific variable is in scope.

Like this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

OBJS = foo.c bar.$$(PLATFORM).c

%.o : %.c
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

foobar_mac: PLATFORM := mac
foobar_mac: $(OBJS)

foobar_win: PLATFORM := win
foobar_win: $(OBJS)
```

Note how we added `.SECONDEXPANSION`, then we escaped the `$(PLATFORM)` reference in `OBJS` as `$$(PLATFORM)` so it would not be expanded when GNU make parses the makefile.

There are various other ways to do this as well.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the cleanest way to go. I was always confused about secondexpansion but now this makes sense. Cheers